# (PHP) The Image cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Tags: php, image, show

I've read almost all topics related to this. i dont know whats causing it.

This is code for showing images

```
<html>
<body>
<?php 

                    mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die("Unable to Connect: ".mysql_error());
                    mysql_select_db("punjabi") or die("Unable to Select Database: ".mysql_error());

                    $sql = "SELECT imagename, mimetype, imagedata
                            FROM images WHERE ID = 1";

                    $result = @mysql_query($sql);
                    if(!$result)
                    {
                        die(mysql_error());
                    }

                    $file = mysql_fetch_array($result);

                    $imagename = $file['imagename'];
                    $mimetype = $file['mimetype'];
                    $imagedata = $file['imagedata'];

                    header("content-type: $mimetype");

                    echo($imagedata);

?>
```

This is the code for inserting images

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Add Post</title>
<style type="text/css">
    *
    {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#333333">

<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
        {


            if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name']))
            {
                die("$uploadfile is not an uploaded file!");
            }

            $uploadfile = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'];
            $uploadname = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
            $uploadtype = $_FILES['uploadfile']['type'];
            $uploaddesc = $_POST['desc'];


            $tempfile = fopen($uploadfile,'rb');
            $filedata = fread($tempfile,filesize($uploadfile));
            $filedata = addslashes($filedata);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO images SET
            imagename = '$uploadname',
            mimetype = '$uploadtype',
            description = '$uploaddesc',
            imagedata = '$filedata'";
            $ok = @mysql_query($sql);
            if (!$ok) die("Database error storing file: " .mysql_error());

            $sql = "Select id from images where imagename = '$uploadname'";
            $result = @mysql_query($sql);
            if(!$result) die(mysql_error());
            if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=1) die(mysql_error());

            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $imageid = $row['id'];

            $title = $_POST['title'];
            $content = $_POST['content'];

            $sql = "INSERT into posts SET
                    title = '$title',
                    content = '$content',
                    imageid = '$imageid'";
            if(!@mysql_query($sql))
            {
                die(mysql_error());
            }


            header("Location:http://localhost/punjabi/adminhome.php");  

        }


?>

<?php else: ?>

    <div id="post">
        <form action="<?php echo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
            Title: <input type="text" name="title" /><br /><br /><br />
            Content:<br /> <textarea cols=100 rows="40" wrap="hard" name="content" /></textarea><br /><br />
            Image: <input type="file" name="uploadfile" /><br /><br />
            Image Desc: <input type="text" name="desc" /><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
        </form>
    </div>

<?php endif; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

And This is the Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE filestore (
-> ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
-> FileName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
-> MimeType VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
-> Description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
-> FileData MEDIUMBLOB
->);
```

And Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why not to use parametrized insert-query instead of `addslashes()`? I think this function modifies your content.

Comment: Do you see `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...` when you directly open generating image .php-script in browser?

Comment: Watch out for inserting unsanitized `$_POST`s into your query directly. SQL injection is a problem!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the headers have already been sent when you do:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
```

So you cannot set the header for the image anymore:

```
header("content-type: $mimetype");
```

Just getting rid of the html (an image is not html / text) before the php tag should solve that.

Comment: Thanks mister :D i removed the html and body tags and it worked :D

Comment: But i'm still confused...i'm using the show image code inside an html document...so how i'm supposed to solve it?

Comment: @AntiSaby The first part of your code (without the html) sends and image to the browser, so to use it in an html document, you would have to use an image tag: `<img src="/your/script.php">`

Comment: @AntiSaby No problem, please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted (the check-mark) if it works for you.